# LocalStorage is not updated when redirecting to another page in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I'm trying to save a value in localStorage and then the page is redirected to another page. but if the value was saved then I enter another value, when I go to the other page the value saved is the first one.
for example, if the value was "red" in the localStorage then I enter the value "blue" after the page is redirected I find that the value saved is "red".

```
<input type="text">
<button>click </button>
```

```js
$('button').on('click', function () {

        callbackLogFun(); 

    });

    function callbackLogFun() { 

    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify($('input').val()));

    callRedirect(); 
 } 

function callRedirect() { 

     window.location.href = "sec-page.html";

}
```

and this how I call it on the second page

```js
localStorage.getItem('user');
```

Comment: Well, localStorage.setItem can take time, so maybe wrap redirect with setTimeout. so after `localStorage.setItem`, `setTimeout(callbackRedirect, 0);`. Try it like this. It may not work if input's value is too much tho

Comment: Please provide how you set localStorageItem in the second page

Comment: I added it @JayNyxed

Comment: it worked but I don't think it's the best way cause maybe I store a lot of inputs value, So it doesn't work @HalilÇakar

Comment: Yes, it's really not a good way like i said it might not catch time, so maybe use some other method to store values like this :) And some users canceling usage of `localStorage`

Comment: That is how you get your value, but in your question you say, that you are setting it on the second page: "if the value was "red" in the localStorage then I enter the value "blue" **after the page is redirected** I find that the value saved is "red""

Comment: I mean when I come back to the first one later and change the value it stays the same. it takes time to be stored like the first comment said, so is there is a way to redirect after saving the value in the localStorage? @JayNyxed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's really a matter of not having enough time to save to localStorage before the page is redirected then you can make the calls to localStorage synchronous:

```
const localStorageAsync = {
    set: function (key, value) {
        return Promise.resolve().then(function () {
            localStorage.setItem(key, value);
        });
    },
    get: function (key) {
        return Promise.resolve().then(function () {
            return localStorage.getItem(key);
        });
    }
};

localStorageAsync
    .set('user', JSON.stringify($('input').val()))
    .then(function() {
        callRedirect();
    })
```

Comment: but where is the redirect function

Comment: This is a very round about way to defer a microtick on localStorage writes, you really could just call `queueMicrotick` after the set when calling the redirect.